# Wrap URL within a string with a href tags using Coldfusion

Tags: regex, url, coldfusion, word-wrap

I have a Coldfusion site that is pulling in a feed that contains urls. I have some control over the urls so I know they will always start with http://. I want to wrap those urls in a href tags so they are clickable but I'm having trouble figuring it out. Any info you guys could give me would be amazing.

Eric

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
<cfset myStr = REReplaceNoCase(myStr, "(\bhttp://[a-z0-9\.\-_:~@##%&/?+=]+)", "<a href=""\1"">\1</a>", "all") />
```

Comment: I think you should add a word boundary anchor: `\bhttp`

Answer (score 2):

Far more better approach:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/487-Using-Verbose-Regular-Expressions-To-Explain-Url-Auto-Linking-In-ColdFusion.htm