# Using replace to Replace Contents

Tags: php, coldfusion

Having following code in PHP

```
krsort($smileys);
                foreach($smileys as $k => $v){
                    $row['message'] = str_replace($k,'<img src="'.$v.'" />',$row['message']);
                }

            //place links if allowed
            if($display_links == 'yes'){
                preg_match('/(http:\/\/[^\s]+)/', $row['message'], $text);
                $hypertext = '<a href="' . $text[0] . '" target="_blank">' . $text[0] . '</a>';
                $row['message'] = preg_replace('/(http:\/\/[^\s]+)/', $hypertext, $row['message']);
            }
```

I a making a replica in coldfusion as:

```
<cfset  structsort(smileys)>
<cfloop collection="#smileys#" item="k">
      <cfset row.message = replace(smileys[k],'<img src="smileys[k]">','all')>
</cfloop>
```

for display links, i am totally lost

Comment: Use [ReReplace](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/REReplace) instead so that you can use the same regular expressions that you have in the PHP code. Some more on the [Regular expression syntax in ColdFusion](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0a38f-7ffb.html).

Comment: I don't know what that replace is supposed to do.. Replace() works as `Replace(string_to_search,string_to_search_for,string_to_replace_with,scope)`. You're missing a parameter because that is just saying search search_string for search_string wrapped in an <img> tag, which it will never find (You can't search "o" for "<img src=o>") and replacing it with 'All' if it did find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure *exactly* what you are after but it seems like you simplyt need pound signs around your #smileys[k]# ... so...

```
<cfset  structsort(smileys)>
<cfloop collection="#smileys#" item="k">
      <cfset row.message = replace(smileys[k],'<img src="#smileys[k]#">','all')>
</cfloop>
```

or...

```
<cfset  structsort(smileys)>
<cfloop collection="#smileys#" item="k">
      <cfset row.message = replace(smileys[k],'<img src=' + smileys[k] + '>','all')>
</cfloop>
```

Wouldn't you feel more comfortable doing all this in script instead of tags? Seems like a bit less of a stretch for you.

Comment: Hi Mark, Script is not my type, i am more proned to work in the cftags, Thanks for the value information, i will post shortly

Answer (score 1):

That PHP code would replace content with A HREF html only in case of http|https string, I can't help you with coldfusion. But I bet you should discover strings starting with http protocol.

Comment: Upvoted because his reputation is too low for him to enter comments.

Comment: Thanks @dan-bracuk, in the meanwhile I got points for another answer

Answer (score 0):

You can learn a lot from very similar questions. This might do the trick for you: [Wrap URL within a string with a href tags using Coldfusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267637/wrap-url-within-a-string-with-a-href-tags-using-coldfusion)

You can adapt the regex code found there into

#### This is a straight translation

```
<cfset  structsort(smileys)>
<cfloop collection="#smileys#" item="k">
    <cfset row.message = ReReplaceNoCase (smileys[k], "((http|https)://[a-z0-9\.\-_:~@##%&/?+=]+(.jpg|.gif|.png))", "<img src='\1'>", "all") />
</cfloop>
```

#### A variant with message keys named like smiles keys

```
<cfset  structsort(smileys)>
<cfset row.message = StructNew()>
<cfloop collection="#smileys#" item="k">
    <cfset row.message[k] = ReReplaceNoCase (smileys[k], "((http|https)://[a-z0-9\.\-_:~@##%&/?+=]+(.jpg|.gif|.png))", "<img src='\1'>", "all") />
</cfloop>
```

With the above, each time you call #smileys[any_key]# after this loop, you can also call #row.message[any_key]#. It's nice if you're trying to keep data coordinated.

#### A variant with an array returning a list of messages

```
<cfset row.message = ArrayNew(1)>
<cfset  structsort(smileys)>
<cfloop collection="#smileys#" item="k">
    <cfset row.message[ArrayLen(row.message)] = ReReplaceNoCase(smileys[k], "((http|https)://[a-z0-9\.\-_:~@##%&/?+=]+(.jpg|.gif|.png))", "<img src='\1'>", "all") />
</cfloop>
```

With the above, you can loop over the array, or convert to to a list to output the conversions.

#### Notes

In each variant, you'll notice `(.jpg|.gif|.png)` at the end of the regex in a pipe-delimited list. You can add more to this list, or remove it.

Also, 'row' has no special significance in cold fusion, I'm not sure if it does in php. To use 'row' is interchangeable with any other custom struct name. In that case, you need to declare it before you can assign keys to it ("message" being a key of the struct "row").

```
<cfset row = structNew()>
```

Would go before any of the above code variations.