# How to replace all anchor tags with a different anchor using regex in ColdFusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I found a similar question here: [Wrap URL within a string with a href tags using Coldfusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267637/wrap-url-within-a-string-with-a-href-tags-using-coldfusion)

But what I want to do is replace  tags with a slightly modified version AFTER the user has submitted it to the server. So here is some typical HTML text that the user will submit to the server:

```
<p>Terminator Genisys is an upcoming 2015 American science fiction action film directed by Alan Taylor. You can find out more by <a href="http://www.imdb.com">clicking here</a></p>
```

What I want to do is replace the `<a href="">` part with a new version which would be like this:

```
...
<a href="http://www.imdb.com" rel="nofollow noreferrer">clicking here</a>
```

So I'm just adding the text `rel="nofollow noreferrer"` to the tag.

I must match anchor tags that contain a href attribute with a URL, not just the URL string itself, because sometimes a user could just do this:

```
<p>Terminator Genisys is an upcoming 2015 American science fiction action film directed by Alan Taylor. You can find out more by <a href=""http://www.imdb.com">http://www.imdb.com</a></p>
```

In which case I still only want to replace the  tag. I don't want to touch the actual anchor text used even though it is a URL.

So how could I rewrite this Regex

```
#REReplaceNoCase(myStr, "(\bhttp://[a-z0-9\.\-_:~@##%&/?+=]+)", "<a href=""\1"">\1</a>", "all")#
```

the other way round, where its selecting  tags and replacing them with my modified text?

Comment: Checkout jSoup. It is perfectly suited for things like this. http://jsoup.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing, this is a really easy task for jQuery (client-side)

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mz1rwo0u/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("a").each(function(e) {
  if ($(this).attr('href').match(/^https?:\/\/(www\.)?imdb\.com/i)) {
    $(this).attr('rel','nofollow noreferrer');
  }});
});
```

(If you right click any of the imdb links and `Inspect Element`, you'll see the rel attribute is added to the imdb links. Note that `View Source` won't reflect the changes, but `Inspect Element` is the important part.)

If you want to effect every a link, you can do this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("a").each(function(e) {
    $(this).attr('rel','nofollow noreferrer');
});
});
```

Finally, you can also use a selector to narrow it down, you might have the content loading into a dom element with the id `contentSection`. You can do...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#contentSection a").each(function(e) {
  if ($(this).attr('href').match(/^https?:\/\/(www\.)?imdb\.com/i)) {
    $(this).attr('rel','nofollow noreferrer');
  }});
});
```

---

It's a bit tougher to reliably parse this in cold fusion without the possibility of accidentally adding it twice (without invoking a tool like jSoup) but the jQuery version is client-side and works by obtaining data from the DOM rather than trying to hot-wire into it (a jSoup implementation works similarly, creating a DOM-like structure you can work with).

When talking about client-side vs server-side, you have to consider the mythical user who doesn't have javascript enabled (or who turns it off with malicious intent). If this functionality is not mission-critical. I'd use JQuery to do it. I've used similar functionality to pop an alert box when the user clicks an outside link on one of my sites.

Here's a jSoup implementation, quick and dirty. jSoup is great for how it selects similarly to jQuery.

```
<cfscript>
jsoup = CreateObject("java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup");
HTMLDocument = jsoup.parse("<A href='http://imdb.com'>test</a> - <A href='http://google.com'>google</a>");

As = htmldocument.select("a");
for (link in As) {
  if (reFindnoCase("^https?:\/\/(www\.)?imdb\.com",link.attr("href"))) {
    link.attr("rel","nofollow noreferrer");
  }
}
writeOutput(htmldocument);
</cfscript>
```

Comment: This is great! do I just remove the match() part if I want to get all anchor tags inside the #contentSection div? because I only used imbd as an example - the URL could be anything. one of the reasons I thought about doing it with CF on the backend was in case the user had no JS enabled... but I guess its overkill for this?

Comment: Yes, you'd just remove the `if....`. And it depends on how mission-critical the presence of this is. Is it's not critical-important, I would use jQuery. I did, however, add a basic jSoup version. @volumeone

Comment: For instance, I said I used similar to pop up an alert to external links on my site--in my case, the alert was a nice feature, but not mission-critical.

Comment: I realised that I need to ColdFusion to do it rather than jQuery. The reason is that what I'm adding is intended for the Google crawl bot. Google bots don't have JavaScript enabled. even if I could make some kind of function that did the replacement on the fly rather than storing it in the database would be ideal

Comment: @volumeone Jsoup is the tool that you need for this then, cold fusion regex will be a huge mess. jSoup, as I demonstrated, makes the change server side and delivers it the browser.

Comment: I put the Jsoup jar file in `ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\WEB-INF\lib` and then wrote this in Application.cfc `this.javaSettings = {
loadPaths: [
"./lib/"
],
loadColdFusionClassPath: true
}` but I get an error from CF saying "The directory or file ./lib/ specified in LOADPATHS does not exist". Any idea whats going wrong?

Comment: Yes, the `./lib` directory does not exist. You are setting the `loadpaths` to a directory named `lib` in the root of your application, which is not where you put the .jar file.